# when dynamic values save in database, some values repeat

Tags: codeigniter

I used following view code to create dynamic inputs by user. My framework is codeigniter.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('</br><div><input class="input form-control"" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
    </script> 
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
   <div class="form-group">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add_field_button">Add More Fields</button> 
    </div>

  </div>
```

My controller to save user inputs at database

```
    function error(){

            $attain = $this->input->post('mytext', true);
            $data2=array(); //<-initialize
                foreach ($attain as $i => $a) { // need index to match other properties
                    //append array
                    $data2[] = array(
                    'mytext' => $a,
                    'projectname'=> $this->input->post('projectname'),
                );
                //for multiple entry in same table
                $this->db->insert_batch('projectem', $data2); 


        }
redirect('Select_ctrl2/ModalAddEmployeesProject');
      }
```

When  user add dynamic inputs it does not save properly.Some values repeat at database.Can anybody helps me?